# Attempting to run a bat file and getting: "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python

When I try to run a batch file using the latest edition of Python I get this error.

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\__init__.py",line 85, in search_function
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 64, in normalize_encoding

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Is there any way I can change code on the lines referenced in the **init**.py file to resolve this?

Here is the code in the init.py file:

```
def normalize_encoding(encoding):

""" Normalize an encoding name.

    Normalization works as follows: all non-alphanumeric
    characters except the dot used for Python package names are
    collapsed and replaced with a single underscore, e.g. '  -;#'
    becomes '_'. Leading and trailing underscores are removed.

    Note that encoding names should be ASCII only.

"""
if isinstance(encoding, bytes):
    encoding = str(encoding, "ascii")

chars = []
punct = False
for c in encoding:
    if c.isalnum() or c == '.':
        if punct and chars:
            chars.append('_')
        if c.isascii():
            chars.append(c)
        punct = False
    else:
        punct = True
return ''.join(chars)

def search_function(encoding):

# Cache lookup
entry = _cache.get(encoding, _unknown)
if entry is not _unknown:
    return entry

# Import the module:
#
# First try to find an alias for the normalized encoding
# name and lookup the module using the aliased name, then try to
# lookup the module using the standard import scheme, i.e. first
# try in the encodings package, then at top-level.
#
norm_encoding = normalize_encoding(encoding)
aliased_encoding = _aliases.get(norm_encoding) or \
                   _aliases.get(norm_encoding.replace('.', '_'))
if aliased_encoding is not None:
    modnames = [aliased_encoding,
                norm_encoding]
else:
    modnames = [norm_encoding]
for modname in modnames:
    if not modname or '.' in modname:
        continue
    try:
        # Import is absolute to prevent the possibly malicious import of a
        # module with side-effects that is not in the 'encodings' package.
        mod = __import__('encodings.' + modname, fromlist=_import_tail,
                         level=0)
    except ImportError:
        # ImportError may occur because 'encodings.(modname)' does not exist,
        # or because it imports a name that does not exist (see mbcs and oem)
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    mod = None

try:
    getregentry = mod.getregentry
except AttributeError:
    # Not a codec module
    mod = None

if mod is None:
    # Cache misses
    _cache[encoding] = None
    return None

# Now ask the module for the registry entry
entry = getregentry()
if not isinstance(entry, codecs.CodecInfo):
    if not 4 <= len(entry) <= 7:
        raise CodecRegistryError('module "%s" (%s) failed to register'
                                 % (mod.__name__, mod.__file__))
    if not callable(entry[0]) or not callable(entry[1]) or \
       (entry[2] is not None and not callable(entry[2])) or \
       (entry[3] is not None and not callable(entry[3])) or \
       (len(entry) > 4 and entry[4] is not None and not callable(entry[4])) or \
       (len(entry) > 5 and entry[5] is not None and not callable(entry[5])):
        raise CodecRegistryError('incompatible codecs in module "%s" (%s)'
                                 % (mod.__name__, mod.__file__))
    if len(entry)<7 or entry[6] is None:
        entry += (None,)*(6-len(entry)) + (mod.__name__.split(".", 1)[1],)
    entry = codecs.CodecInfo(*entry)

# Cache the codec registry entry
_cache[encoding] = entry

# Register its aliases (without overwriting previously registered
# aliases)
try:
    codecaliases = mod.getaliases()
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    for alias in codecaliases:
        if alias not in _aliases:
            _aliases[alias] = modname

# Return the registry entry
return entry

# Register the search_function in the Python codec registry
codecs.register(search_function)

if sys.platform == 'win32':
# bpo-671666, bpo-46668: If Python does not implement a codec for current
# Windows ANSI code page, use the "mbcs" codec instead:
# WideCharToMultiByte() and MultiByteToWideChar() functions with CP_ACP.

# Python does not support custom code pages.
def _alias_mbcs(encoding):
    try:
        import _winapi
        ansi_code_page = "cp%s" % _winapi.GetACP()
        if encoding == ansi_code_page:
            import encodings.mbcs
            return encodings.mbcs.getregentry()
    except ImportError:
        # Imports may fail while we are shutting down
        pass

codecs.register(_alias_mbcs)
```

Any help appreciated. Not sure exactly what I could change in the code to resolve the issue.

Comment: you are running < python3.7 python .. str.isascii() was introduced to then - upgrade